# Error on foreach on array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Im having some issues regarding a array of objects, for some reason i cant access the id of each object, it gives me a error of:

```
ErrorException in SController.php line 51:
Undefined index: id
```

In my controlller method:

```
public function today()
    {
        $todayMatches = new SportRadarService();
        $temp = [];

        foreach ($todayMatches->getAllMatchesFromDate() as $match){
           array_push($temp,$match["id"]);
        }
        return $temp;

    }
```

Sample data from "$todayMatches->getAllMatchesFromDate()":

```
[
{
"id": "sr:11964344",
"scheduled": "2017-08-09T15:00:00+00:00",
},
{
"id": "sr:767667",
"scheduled": "2017-08-012T15:00:00+00:00",
},
....
]
```

Comment: I guess match is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

It's a collection, an Object. Try:

```
array_push($temp,$match->id);
```

Comment: thats not collection